# ZF Render an action and get the html in another action

Tags: zend-framework, view, frameworks, action, render

What I want to do with Zend Framework is to render the action Y from the action X and to obtain the html:

Example:

```
public xAction(){
     $html = some_function_that_render_action('y');
}

public yAction(){
     $this->view->somedata = 'sometext';
}
```

where the y view is something like:

```
<h1>Y View</h1>
<p>Somedata = <?php echo $this->somedata ?></p>
```

I fount the action helper, but I cannot use it from a controller. How can I solve it?
It is possible?

Comment: Does ZF support 'partials'? Have xAction and yAction call their specific templates, and within these specific templates they call a shared partial template.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way to do what you want.

```
public function xAction()
{
    $this->_helper
         ->viewRenderer
         ->setRender('y'); // render y.phtml viewscript instead of x.phtml

    $this->yAction();

    // now yAction has been called and zend view will render y.phtml instead of x.phtml
}

public function yAction()
{
    // action code here that assigns to the view.
}
```

Instead of using the [ViewRenderer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) to set the view script to use, you could also call yAction as I showed above, but get the html by calling `$html = $this->view->render('controller/y.phtml');`

See also the [ActionStack helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.actionstack).

Comment: your first solution not solve my problem: it change the view of the action, but I only need the html.

Comment: your second solution return the html, but don't assign the correct data to the view (don't call the action).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Action View Helper from the controller

```
public function xAction()
{
    $html = $this->view->action(
        'y',
        $this->getRequest()->getControllerName(),
        null,
        $this->getRequest()->getParams()
    );
}

public function yAction()
{
    // action code here that assigns to the view.
}
```

It's not very beautiful but it works well and you don't have to use `$view->setScriptPath($this->view->getScriptPaths());`

This helper creates a new Zend_Controller_Request for yAction(), so you can give your own parameters as 4th argument or use `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` to spread the request parameters of xAction().

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this "solution", it's not what I want to do, but it works, if someone found the real solution, please answer here.

```
public function xAction(){
    $data = $this->_prepareData();
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->somedata = $data;
    $view->setScriptPath($this->view->getScriptPaths());

    $html = $view->render('controller/y.phtml');
}
```

Comment: Calling new Zend_View() reset the view and the helper registered in other folder and namespace has to be redefine